# Samba networking with a domain-joined computer

Tags: windows, networking, ubuntu, domain, samba

I have two computers connected to the same linksys router - one running Ubuntu 8.04 and one running Windows 7.  The Windows computer is part of a work domain (when connected via VPN).  I'm trying to also create a home network so I can access the linux server from Windows.

From what I understand, I have to first create a Windows workgroup and then configure Samba on linux to join the Windows network.  So in Windows, I went to Control Panel -> Network and Internet -> HomeGroup and got the following message:

> There is currently no homegroup on your network.  Because this computer also belongs to a domain, you can't create your own homegroup, but can join one created by someone on your network.

Can I use Samba to create a homegroup?  Is there any other way to create a Windows workgroup?  Or am I barking up the wrong tree completely?

Answer (score 1):

Don't bark. Homegroup can be seen as an enhancement to workgroup. Samba is probably not aware of it. [You can read about home group, work group and domain here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/What-is-the-difference-between-a-domain-a-workgroup-and-a-homegroup). But actually thay are not relevant to your needs. Both workgroup and homegroup are just ways too make sharing resources between peer computers easier. You are using linux. So easier is not relevant to you.

You just have to configure samba to share some folder. And in the windows start type:

```
\\sambaserver\theshare
```

You will be prompted for a user and a password ( of a linux account ) and you should be good to go.

Comment: +1 for 'So easier is not relevant to you.'